# The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am using google cloud sql with appengine.

I am getting `com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.` despite I am not using the Datasotre API.

I think according to the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide#access_limits that the data-size limit is 16MB served in 60 seconds.

My data size is around 1 MB and my response is definitely  less than 1 minute. If I try with smaller data, everything works correctly.

So, why is the exception thrown ? what is the problem ?
Is it a bug in google app engine? or is there a size-limitation , where is it documented ? or what ?

Comment: Datastore has a limit of 1Mb per entity. Are you sure you use Cloud SQL? Also note that sessions use Datastore under the hood, so if you save more than 1Mb in session you could get this exception.

Comment: @PeterKnego I use Cloud SQL for sure. By sessions, do you mean HttpSession ?

Comment: Yes, specifically GAE session support: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions

Comment: @PeterKnego That 's it. I save the data in the session. This is what caused the exception. Thanks.

Comment: I'll write an answer then..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because of [GAE sessions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions), which under the hood use GAE Datastore to save session objects. This exception is thrown if more than 1Mb data is stored in session.

Comment: How you've solved the issue? You removed the data from the session somehow?

Comment: It has been two years, I do not remember how exactly I solved this. I may have removed the data from session; reload it from database every time. Or I have divided the data into  two objects; each object is less than 1MB and store them in the session with two different keys.