# Exception The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available occured in ndb.put_multi() method

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting `The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.` error after putting 4853 entities into datastore. I have used `ndb.put_multi()` method to insert multiple entities in single call.

As per my understanding we can make `5,00,000` calls in one day to datastore. Can anyone please shed light on why my application is getting stopped by GAE? This same code runs on my local app server.

I have seen this question posted on SO but that question asks about quota reset. [The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338092/the-request-to-api-call-datastore-v3-put-was-too-large)

Comment: The AppEngine dashboard shows usage and quotes -- what does it say about datastore writes?

Comment: Dashboard says that my application has exceeded 'Datastore Write Operations' threshold of '0.05 of 0.05 Million Ops' operations. I am pretty much sure that my application has put 4853 entities in less than 100 calls to data store. Then also GAE has shot down my application. Can you please give some hint on why this happens?

Comment: tried diagnosis with appstatsz? :) https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats